# Can I add a comment before the create procedure statement?

Tags: sql-server, comments, flyway

I am using SQL Server.

When using Flyway(v5.0.7), comments created outside the procedure are deleted.

Is there a way to include it without deleting it?

```
/*
=================================================================
Name   : SELECT_MY_HERO
TYPE : PROCEDURE
SINCE   : 2020-11-18
WRITER   : minam
DESCRIPTION : SELECT MY HERO
USAGE     : EXEC SELECT_MY_HERO 1
SERVER    : MS_SQL_MINE
=================================================================
*/
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SELECT_MY_HERO
    @id INTEGER
AS
..
```

When the Flyway is migrate that. It is going to delete comment outside the procedure syntax.

So I want to know is there a solution that keep the comment.

Comment: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1362

Comment: @DaleK 
Thanks for the answer. I solved that upgrade to 5.1.0

Comment: Have you considered moving to the current version - 7.11? 5.1 is now quite elderly

Comment: @JuliaHayward I want. but Im afraid its not easy bcuz It's on company work...

Answer (score 1):

I used v5.0.7 version of Flyway-core.

and then I upgraded to 5.1.0 .

Finally It's work!